# Are we allowed to call gcc's simd_fast_mersenne_twister_engine (sfmt19937_64) directly?

Tags: c++, gcc, random

It looks like gcc supports simd mt since [GCC 4.8](https://isocpp.org/blog/2013/03/gcc-4.8-released)

> - SSE optimized normal_distribution and simd_fast_mersenne_twister_engine.

Is there a way to call GCC's `sfmt19937_64` directly?

Comment: If you are not afraid of the compiler police you can use it.  Also your code will be unportable.

Comment: So we are not allowed. But how to call it un-portably then?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any internal use of `simd_fast_mersenne_twister_engine` in libstdc++, and it's header `<ext/random>` is an installed header file.  Based on that, it has to be intended for application use and is part of the public API.

Comment: Would you please give me some code example about how to call `sfmt19937_64` ?